# Notify a View Controller when it's parent's TabBarController's index was changed programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm changing my `TabBarController` `index` property programmatically, like so:

```
self.navigationController.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Is there any way of the View Controller, that subsequently gets shown, knowing that the change in tab came from the code and not from the user tapping the tab.

My use-case: I download/refresh data on `viewDidLoad`, and I don't really want to be doing it in `viewDidAppear` each time, so I'm hoping there's a way I can manually trigger this refresh of data, when I change the tab programmatically?

Comment: This is why you should not put loading code in view controllers.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Would be good to know where to put it, and not just where not to put it...

Comment: There's a few places it can go besides view controllers. This might help you get away from the mega view controller approach. http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in way of knowing this. You can always add a boolean flag to the controller instance and set it when switching to it from the code.